# Do moral choices affect gameplay?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been playing a while now and I'm kind of roleplaying a lawful good character, and I'm wondering what the impact of doing "evil" quests are? I have one for Boethia about lieing to a priest to then go sacrifice him at an alter, which I'm not going to do. Will this affect my game?

I know it's annoying to have the quest the whole time and not be able to clear it off without being naughty.

I've also reached a point where

> Esbern and Delphine are in Sky Temple, and ask me to kill Paarthonax, which I don't want to do. So what are the outcomes? If I kill him I assume I get to rebuild the Blades, and if I don't? I'm still mates with the Greybeards?

Comment: These are two separate questions, with two separate, mostly unrelated answers: I'd separate your question about the quest you buried in spoiler markdown into a new one.

Comment: the spoiler question is a duplicate ftr.

Comment: I still feel the spoiler is a moral choice, it's about caring about the character and as such will affect your game play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your overall question, yes the choices you make can affect your gameplay. If you do enough acts of evil that are witnessed in areas then guards will attack  you on site, heck even towns folk will attack you on site eventually. This can make completing any quests in those towns very difficult. Even if you are not caught the game is still aware of what is going on and you will often get snide passing remarks from the guards. I have never been spotted pick pocketing for example (my bounty level is 0). However they often threaten to make me lose my hand if they catch it in their pocket (to which I then have to steal all they have on them to prove a point, they wont catch me :)).

However, to address your second question which is hidden in the spoiler text. This is not a specific moral question in my opinion as it really comes down to how you want your character to feel about the situation. There is plenty of evidence on each side to support both of their views so neither one is truly evil or good. It just comes down to an Us or Them choice (which I skipped). There are quite a few of these set ups through out the game, the more obvious one is the Imperials vs the Storm Cloaks which my friends and I argue about all the time on which side is right :)

Comment: The remarks from the guards about catching you pickpocketing come up just because you have a high enough pickpocket skill. Theoretically you could never pick a single pocket but still get those remarks because you trained/used skill books to get your skill high enough. Doesn't affect the core of your answer, but an interesting thing to note :)

Comment: @PeterL Haha, True ... But I still question the morality of paying someone to teach you to pick pockets as there are only 2 skill books in the world for each skill in vanilla skyrim ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are no consequences for not completing side quests other than not getting the rewards, if any. As for your spoiler question: you can't please everyone, it doesn't matter later which group you want to like you because there aren't any more quests or work or interesting dialog from them once the deed is done or not done.

You can always save and reload to check out both branches.